# How can I refresh a JScrollPane after choosing an element from a JComboBox?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have a JComboBox, and I want to load in a JScrollPane a different content everytime I choose a different element from the JComboBox. The content consists of a various number of JLabels and JTextFields.

What I have done:

```
JScrollPane scrollPane;
JComboBox combo;

JPanel back = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
combo = new JComboBox({ "Bird", "Cat", "Dog", "Rabbit", "Pig" });
combo.addActionListener(new AnimalLoader());
scrollPane = showPanel((String) combo.getSelectedItem());

back.add(combo, BorderLayout.NORTH);
back.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

back.setVisible(true);

protected JScrollPane showPanel(String name)
{
     JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel(new JLabel(name));
     scrollPane = new JScrollPane(contentPanel);

     return scrollPane;
}

private class AnimalLoader implements ActionListener
{
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
     {
            JComboBox cb = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
            String selected = (String) cb.getSelectedItem();
            scrollPane = showPanel(selected);              
     }
}
```

I didn't manage to make this reload a different JScrollPane when I choose another item.
Only the JScrollPane that belongs to the first item (the default one) of the JComboBox is loaded.

Any ideas of what I've done wrong please?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an SSCCE (http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
scrollPane = showPanel(selected);
```

Don't create a new scoll pane when you select an item. Instead you need to change the panel that is contained in the viewport of the scroll pane. That is, your "showPanel" method should return the panel, not a scrollpane. Then you can use:

```
scrollPane.setViewportView( showPanel(selected) );
```

Next time a proper SSCCE should be posted.

Comment: Thanks camickr, your answers never fail. Next time I will post a better SSCCE.

Answer (score 1):

There is no evidence the newly created JScrollPane is ever added to anything.

I would try either of:

1. Add a JPanel with a CardLayout to
   the JScrollPane, and add other
   collections of components to the
   JPanel.
2. Call
   setViewportView(Component view) on
   the existing JScrollPane.

Comment: The JScrollPane is added to a JPanel after creation. I didn't post all the code, because it's a complex application. I have done what you said. `JPanel centerPanel;
     centerPanel = new JPanel(new JLabel("Test"));
     productsPane = new JScrollPane(centerPanel);`

Comment: I followed the sun example on JComboBoxes from http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#uneditable

Comment: Then you'll need to post enough information so your question is answerable.  An [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) would do nicely as Andrew mentions in his first comment to your post above.

Comment: I have never made an SSCCE... I have tried now. Tell me if its ok please.

Answer (score 0):

panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();

Answer (score 0):

As you are using this [example](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/ComboBoxDemoProject/src/components/ComboBoxDemo.java), try this variation at line 73, near the end of the `ComboBoxDemo` constructor:

```
//Lay out the demo.
add(petList, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(picture);
jsp.getViewport().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
add(jsp, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20,20,20,20));
```